# Two questions on Do Carmo’s definition of variation of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

On page 345 of *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* by Manfredo Do Carmo there is the following definition of variation of a curve:

> Let $\alpha \colon [0, l] \to S$ be a regular parametrised curve, where the parameter $s$ is the arc length. A variation of $\alpha$ is a **differentiable** map $h \colon [0, l] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to S$ such that $h(s, 0) = \alpha(s)$ for all $s \in (0, l].$

I have two questions regarding this defintion:

1. Shouldn’t $h(s, 0) = \alpha(s)$ also hold for $s = 0$?
2. What does it mean for $h$ to be differentiable on $[0, l] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon),$ which is not an open set?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, because the idea is that this concept is defined for every *continuous* curve. If we imposed that the equality holds when $s=0$, that would mean that $\alpha$ would be differentiable.
2. So what? Isn't the map $f\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$ differentiable?

Comment: 1. $\alpha$ is supposed to be $\mathcal{C}^\infty,$ so requiring that $h(0, 0) = \alpha(0)$ wouldn’t change anything right?

Comment: 2. I have only seen a definition of differentiability on non-open sets for one-variable functions.

Comment: 1. Where is it that Do Carmo says that $\alpha$ is $C^\infty$? I have a copy of the book before my eyes and I didn't sse that. 2. My guess then is that, for him, a function definid on an arbitrary set is differentiable if it is the restriction to that set of a differentiable function defined on an open set.

Comment: 1. In the first paragraph of section 1-2.

Comment: 2. Okay, thanks.

Comment: 1. You are right. Do Carmo was definitely sloppy here.